# how to restore visual studio debug window to show full text?

Tags: visual-studio

when I run Visual studio 2019 in debug mode , the output debug window only shows odd characters  .ex

f4f

[20

how do i restore the debug window to show everything ?

Answer (score 0):

Silly - i just needed to maximize the window .